# Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

When I tried to use Fb and Twitter authentication with firebase it shows below error. Same error shows both on the iOS device and simulator. Could you tell me how to sort out this issue? I'm using `Ionic 3` app.

***Note:*** This is working fine on Android device though.

I have used this article: [**Ionic Social Login using Firebase**](https://javebratt.com/ionic-social-login-firebase/)

> Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server

This is the error:

[image]

.ts

```
 async loginWithFacebook(): Promise<string> {
    try {
      const response = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
      const result = await this.afAuth.auth.getRedirectResult();
      return result.additionalUserInfo.profile.email;
      }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Comment: Is it a PWA or an installed app? If I recall correctly you can't use signInWithRedirect() on hybrid apps since the protocol isn't https:// but file://

Comment: This is an installed app (native app). It is working fine on Android. So why this is only on iOS? @javebratt

Comment: The issue appears to be that ionic now defaults to WKWebView (http://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/) which has issues with Firebase. The suggested workaround at this time is to downgrade to UIWebView, but WKWebView support would prevent the issue altogether.

Comment: Yes, But I cannot do that since this app must support the iPhoneX and iOS 11.2+. @bojeil